# Is there an appropriate hypothesis test: Two samples, one only with one datapoint, non-normal?

Tags: predictive-modeling, skewness, sign-test, mann-whitney

I have two 'samples'.

1. The first consists of approx. 400 physical measurements of a quantity (taken over one hour, and the real situation is not a steady state). They show a very skewed distribution for which the theoretical model is not known, and the values can lie between 0 and (theoretically) +inf.
2. The second 'sample' unfortunately consists of only one data point, as it is derived by modelling the physics of the scenario pretending it is a steady state in this hour. (I am not really sure if I should consider this as a mean for this hour, or as just one measurement in the hypothesis testing).

I want to find ways to quantify if the model describes the data well enough. I thought I could maybe use hypothesis testing, but I am not sure if the information I have here is sufficient. I first thought I'd do a Mann-Whitney U test, but (I think) one data point is too little.  Would this be a case where I can just use the t-test even if the data is skewed? Would the One Sample Sign Test be appropriate? Is there a totally different approach I could consider?

I am new to this, feel like I am lost with this zoo of existing hypothesis tests.

Comment: Are you trying to compare steady state with "not a steady state" with the help of hypothesis ? Further, what is quantity under reference ?

Comment: The quantity is wind speed. I have the measurements over an hour, and then I have one modeled value that is supposed to represent this hour. The model assumes a steady state over this one hour.

Comment: The part "The second 'sample' unfortunately consists of only one data point, as it is derived by modelling the physics of the scenario pretending it is a steady state in this hour. (I am not really sure if I should consider this as a mean for this hour, or as just one measurement in the hypothesis testing). " is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply t-test assuming modelled mean as a population mean calculated under the assumption that a steadystate existed. The observed sample data (n = 400) for speed of wind can be used to compute sample-mean. If you have highly skewed data, you may remove outlier data in the sample. Mann-Whitney U test is a non_parametric test- probability-based test. Your data does not meet its condtions